# VBA Run-time error '1004' - Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running into

> Run-time error '1004' - Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

What I'm trying to accomplish here is a line chart which will be dynamic and able to change as more data gets inputted into the spreadsheet.

```
Sub HistoricalDemand()

Dim lRow As Integer
' Creates a line chart for the demand column

Range("E2:E" & lRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("E2:E")
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Historical Demand"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Historical Demand"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 17).ParagraphFormat
    .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
    .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select

lRow = wsData.Range("E" & wsData.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `Source:=Range("E2:E")` is not a valid range... you are missing a row number at the end

Comment: @braX I would like the last row # to be lRow which I defined in the code at the end

Comment: It doesnt work like that - move the `lRow` line to the top if you want to use it like that.

Comment: that, and `Range("E2:E" & lRow).Select` evaluates to `Range("E2:E0").Select` and there is no Row 0.

Comment: Okay so it turns out, I will not need to use lRow... I can just set the range to "E:E" and it works just the same... I understand now what you are talking about